# Sharing configuration across vagrantfiles

Tags: vagrant

We have multiple projects that each are going to use Vagrant for managing their development environments. We're happily using Chef for provisioning and all that's working fine. But, we're finding that our Vagrantfiles have a lot of cut'n'paste between them. We'd like to consolidate our Vagrantfile definitions so that they can share from a common Vagrantfile-library (either locally or installed from some remote location). Is this a thing?

Comment: Not sure if it exists but would be useful.

Comment: Use git to manage your Vagrantfile repository, Gitlab would be a good option. I am not aware of any existing tools that meets your requirements.

Comment: What about using ruby includes?

Answer (score 0):

One good way could be to include the common directives of your `Vagrantfile` in a custom box.

A box is just a `.tar` or `tar.gz` file containing all the stuff needed by the provider for running the Vagrant instances. As far as I know, all provider-specific formats allow adding a `Vagrantfile` with common settings to the box.